# Asset saves in Draft but not showing up in Preview - help!

Tags: entries, assets

I have saved an asset to the Assets tab in Craft and successfully uploaded it into an article I'm creating. I deleted the picture it was replacing, and then uploaded it. It saves in draft, but doesn't show up when I look in the preview. All other stuff (like copy I wrote) DOES show up, so I know it's an asset issue. Please advise, thank you!

Comment: Does this happen for other assets or just that one?

Comment: well it's the whole article actually. I noticed that copy isn't saving either...

Comment: Could be a host/server issue? Did it ever work correctly?

Comment: Yes, it was a link redirect mishap...resolved now. THank you!